# Vuetify 2 and NetSuite

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js, netsuite

I'm trying to use Vuetify 2 withing NetSuite to make a custom dashboard.

Approach:

- Suitelet script with inlinehtml field to display the vue_dashboard.html

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(['N/file', 'N/render', 'N/runtime', 'N/search','./ns_script_util'],
    /**
 * @param{file} file
 * @param{render} render
 * @param{runtime} runtime
 * @param{search} search
 */
    (file, render, runtime, search,util) => {
        /**
         * Defines the Suitelet script trigger point.
         * @param {Object} scriptContext
         * @param {ServerRequest} scriptContext.request - Incoming request
         * @param {ServerResponse} scriptContext.response - Suitelet response
         * @since 2015.2
         */
        const onRequest = (scriptContext) => {

            const pageRenderer = render.create();
            const htmlFileData = getHtmlTemplate('vue_dashboard.html','dash_component.js');
            const htmlFile = file.load({
                id: htmlFileData['vue_dashboard.html'].id
            });

            
            pageRenderer.templateContent = htmlFile.getContents();
            pageRenderer.addCustomDataSource({
                format: render.DataSource.OBJECT,
                alias: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    files: {
                        componentLogic: htmlFileData['dash_component.js'].url
                    }
                }
            });

            scriptContext.response.write(pageRenderer.renderAsString());
        }

        const getHtmlTemplate = (htmlPage, htmlLogic) => {
            const htmlPageData = {};
            search.create({
                type: 'file',
                filters: [['name', 'is', htmlPage], 'OR', ['name', 'is', htmlLogic]],
                columns: ['name', 'url']
            }).run().each(resultSet => {
                htmlPageData[resultSet.getValue({ name: 'name' })] = {
                    url: resultSet.getValue({ name: 'url' }),
                    id: resultSet.id
                };
                return true;
            });
            return htmlPageData;
        }
        
        return {onRequest}

    });
```

- vue_dashboard.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="app-template-table">
      <v-app>
      
      <v-app-bar color = "#BBDEFB">
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon
          variant="text"
          @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"
        ></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
  
        <v-toolbar-title>TEST APP</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn icon>
          <v-icon>mdi-home-outline</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn icon>
          <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-app-bar>

      <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" location="left" temporary>
        <v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" link>
          <v-list-item-icon> <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon> </v-list-item-icon>
          <v-list-item-content> <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title> </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-navigation-drawer>

      <v-content>
      <p>test</p>
    </v-content>

    </v-app>
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.6.5/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.6.10/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="${JSON.files.componentLogic}"></script>
    
    
    <!-- <script>
      const { createApp } = Vue;
      const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;
      
      const vuetify = createVuetify();
      
      const app = createApp({
        template: "#app-template-table", 
      })
        .use(vuetify)
        .mount("#app");
    </script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

- dash_compinent.js contains the vue mounting function

```js
const myForm = {
    template: '#app-template-table',
    data: () => ({
        drawer: false,
        group: null,
        items: [
          {
            title:'Home',
            icon:'mdi-home-outline'
          },
          {
            title: 'P1',
            icon: 'mdi-file-document-multiple',
          },
          {
            title: 'P2',
            icon: 'mdi-card-account-details-outline',
          },
          {
            title: 'P3',
            icon: 'mdi-account-group-outline',
          }
        ]
      }),
    mounted() {
        console.log('Logic was loaded');
    }
}

new Vue({
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    render: h => h(myForm)
}).$mount("#app")
```

As you can see, I'm using CDN. With that said, how do I define routers with this?

I can make router using NPM and localhosting but I wanted to host everything in NetSuite file cabinet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about vue but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73758642/react-js-and-suitelet/73758791#73758791) covers how I typically embed react apps on a Suitelet page.

Then if you need routing on the app you'll use a hash router.

By injecting this into an inline html field the user feels like they've stayed in Netsuite since all the normal nav bars will be available.

The benefit of this over page replacement is that the current url of the page can be used for API calls back to Netsuite.

i.e. a GET without an 'action' parameter loads the page.
a GET or POST with an action parameter calls other functions in your suitelet that can be used to populate your app.

Comment: When you say current URL of the page, do you refer to the script deployment URL? If so, I'm still using a parameters on the headers to define/decide which js to load on my app. Does that sound right? I don't quite get the hash router you're saying but will look into it

Comment: the script deployment url can have other parameters added to it and Netsuite will still call your suitelet properly as long as you don't overrwite the script and deployment id parameters.