# Chunk files failed to load Status of 404 on Netsuite hosted Angular 17 app using jsPDF

Tags: angular, netsuite, jspdf

I have created an Angular 17 app using the jsPDF library that is to be hosted in Netsuite. The app runs fine when using ng serve. But when I upload to Netsuite where it is hosted and run from there I get the errors

> "chunk-RS6LHQUM.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded
> with a status of 404 ()" "chunk-G5ZMUUOF.js:1  Failed to load
> resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
> "chunk-ELAEEMD4.js:1  Failed to load resource: the server responded
> with a status of 404 ()"

This is the code in index.html file referencing the location of the chunk files:

These seem to load fine I get know errors here.
The occurs when this code is run

`const doc = new jspdf('p', 'in', 'letter');`

It appears that files are loaded in the preload find, but when it is time to access them they can't be found. Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

I have isolate the error to occur when creating a new jspdf object.

Comment: There would be different answers depending on how you are serving your app. Are you trying to extend functionality in the NetSuite UI? Trying to add something to a SuiteCommerce site?

Comment: I am trying to extend functionality in the NetSuite UI.  I am serving the app in Netsuite.  The angular files including the chunk files are being stored and accessed from file cabient in Netsuite.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to used chunked files for an app that is extending the Netsuite then the issue is likely that when you upload a file to the Netsuite file cabinet its addressable url will not match its filename. eg. a file uploaded as logo.jpg might have url https://123456.app.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=99999999&c=123456&h=fZSzufXp-1fegXU4k1oUIWPpj3BurMcCO8QgsNd6W5836dL-

so you will have lost names like appname.chunk1.js

1. Don't chunk. If someone is running Netsuite they should have good bandwidth already.
2. Don't use Angular (and don't chunk). I have some pretty sophisticated React apps running in Suitelets. I just looked at one of them and the non-chunked app size is 285k. This is not a large file by today's standards. Using preact or Vue would can make your app files even smaller.
3. Write a dynamic import resolver. [Webpack Require From](https://github.com/agoldis/webpack-require-from) is an interesting option. I haven't used it but the functionality is what you'd need to turn your chunk names back into Netsuite file urls. From the NetSuite UI you'd use that library in conjunction with a Suitelet that does file lookup. The function getFileURL in [React JS and Suitelet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73758642/react-js-and-suitelet/73758791#73758791) would be a starting point.